# How to properly encrypt Elasticsearch instance with KMS

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, encryption, elasticsearch, amazon-kms

I will use my Rails/Mysql/Elasticsearch for processing some sensitive data, so I want to encrypt my data at rest.

It is clear to me that I can use AWS KMS to [encrypt data in Mysql](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html). It's important for me that this encryption is transparent for my application.

But now I'm concerned about indexes and data gathered by Elasticsearch. Is there a similar way to transparently encrypt data there?

I am interested in solutions both for Elasticsearch-as-an-application as well as [AWS Elasticsearch-as-service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-elasticsearch-service.html) as I have not decided what I'll be using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I mentioned in the answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942918/does-aws-rds-encryption-with-kms-affect-performance), AWS does not support encryption-at-rest for the ElasticSearch service at this time. For encryption-in-transit you can use HTTPS connections, as per the AWS Support response to [this question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=678318):

> You can use https for encrypted communication with your domain.
>
> Communication between nodes is not encrypted. The nodes themselves are
>   hosted within our VPC, and all communication between nodes remains
>   within it.

If you need encryption-at-rest for ElasticSearch, you will have to setup your own ElasticSearch cluster on EC2 instances, and use encrypted EBS volumes.

Comment: Thank your for your effort answering my questions, I really appreciate it!

Comment: That only solves encryption at disk level. If you have a requirement of using encryption key for each client / index, I don't know of any supported way to encrypt data using KMS or other encryption keys.

Answer (score 0):

Now AWS has come up with encryption for their Elasticseach services. You can go through [link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/encryption-at-rest-now-available-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service/)